# Why my cpu spend so much time on system?

Tags: kernel, process, cpu, top

```
top - 08:58:42 up 20 days,  8:23,  1 user,  load average: 67.17, 58.94, 62.75
Tasks: 630 total,  40 running, 524 sleeping,   0 stopped,  66 zombie
Cpu(s): 57.3%us, 41.6%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.1%hi,  1.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  16331504k total, 15494480k used,   837024k free,  4227840k buffers
Swap:  4194296k total,   263000k used,  3931296k free,  2079368k cached
```

What's the problem? Only 57.3% usage. 41.6% sy. What is that?

Comment: us is user and sy is system. This tells you the percentage of cpu time spent in userspace (us) and in the kernel (sy)

Comment: what kind of system do you use because a load of 58 is just monstrous are you on 64core server ?

Comment: 66 zombie processes is funny, too.

Comment: Why so much? Or why so little? You're starting right at the answer. You cut the lines that show which processes are causing that load. We can't help you. Read the rest of the output from `top`.

Comment: My CPU spend so much time on kernel. But why at kernel?

Answer (score 3):

The system load is mostly caused by applications calling kernel functions. It's userspace vs. kernel space. You can call `strace -c -p $PID` for those processes which cause the highest CPU load. That shows you which syscalls are done and how often.

Comment: This answer helped me resolve an issue with too many calls to flock(2).

Comment: `strace` helps! For new users with a long process: you need to let it run for a while and then use `Ctrl+C` to kill it if you cannot wait (or if you feel puzzled why there is not output).